# jwrapper xml config include files for SharedAppFolder?

Tags: jwrapper

can I configure jwrapper's xml so that a directory/file is included and put into the shared folder, not into the app folder ?

mydir/myfolder/foo

I would like to access it  via
JWSystem.getAllAppVersionsSharedFolder()

Thank you
Peter

Answer (score 0):

You can't have JWrapper copy files into the shared folder as it doesn't really fit in with how JWrapper works conceptually.

When you release a new version of your app the updated files will all be contained within the app folder (JWSystem.getAppFolder).  From there you can save files that you want to remain consistent across versions to the all app versions shared folder (JWSystem.getAllAppVersionsSharedFolder).

However, managing the consistency of those files across versions and how they are updated is something that your app has to do since it will require context about what the files are and how they should be modified, updated etc.

If its just a case of overwriting files with the latest version then there's no real need to put them in the shared folder, you can just access the files bundled with your latest app version via the JWSystem.getAppFolder call.